# How To Replace Background Color Based on String Value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've trying this to create a dinamic background color. (Without reload all page)

```
if (status_val.length > 0) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (e) {
            $("#status_" + ID).html(status_val);

            var setstatus = $("#status_" + ID);

            if (setstatus.html().value == "Active") {
                setstatus.style.background = "green";
                return (false);
            } else if (setstatus.html().value == "Inactive") {
                setstatus.style.background = "red";
                return (false);
            }
            return (true);

        }
    });
}
```

seems to only doing String function not the background. How can I replace selected background color?

Comment: try changing `setstatus.style.background="green";` to `setstatus.style.backgroundColor="green";` because background will englobe the whole thing( background image, repeat or not, the position,...) and maybe what you are looking for is a specific thing like the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setstatus` refers to a jQuery object, not a DOM element. To set style properties, you use jQuery's `css` function.

To set *just* the background color, use `background-color`:

```
setstatus.css("background-color", "green");
```

Setting `background` will clear any other background styles.

---

Side notes (#1 is particularly important):

1. The `html` accessor returns a string. Strings don't have a `.value` property. Just remove that.
2. Rather than looking up the element multiple times, consider doing the `var setstatus = $("#status_" + ID);` **once**, before calling `.html`.
3. `return` isn't a function, there's almost never a need to put its operand in parentheses (though doing so is harmless).
4. The return value of the `success` callback is completely ignored; there's no point in using a value with `return` in that case.
5. There's no need to go get the HTML from the element you just set it on, you have it in `status_val`.

So taking all of that together:

```
if (status_val.length > 0) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (e) {
            var setstatus = $("#status_" + ID);
            setstatus.html(status_val);

            if (status_val == "Active") {
                setstatus.css("background-color", "green");
            } else if (status_val == "Inactive") {
                setstatus.css("background-color", "red");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Finally, rather than directly manipulating the style of the element, consider using classes to represent the states, and having the classes assign the colors. That helps keep your styling in one place (the stylesheet).

Okay, **really** finally: What if the value isn't `"Active"` or `"Inactive"`? In the above, you'll never change the background color. If those are the only two possibilities, consider just using `else`, not `else if`.

---

**Live Example** using `setTimeout` to emulate the ajax call:

```js
var ID = "xyz";
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  var status_val = $(this).val();

  if (status_val.length > 0) {

    setTimeout(function(e) {
      var setstatus = $("#status_" + ID);
      setstatus.html(status_val);

      if (status_val == "Active") {
        setstatus.css("background-color", "green");
      } else if (status_val == "Inactive") {
        setstatus.css("background-color", "red");
      }
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Active">
<input type="button" value="Inactive">
<div id="status_xyz">This is the status_xyz element</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate that. But still need full reload to replace background color.

Comment: @DavidRivaldy: No, you don't.

Comment: excuse me, sir. When I increase width. that's look like only highlight the string value. And background color does not replaced.

Comment: @DavidRivaldy: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean about increasing the width, only highlighting the string value, etc. Probably best to ask a new question including your HTML and identifying what's happening and what you want to have happen instead.